# Misprinting Statement of Invoices

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to print list of invoices on a single document with a same document number but what happens is, it prints the first statement correctly  but when it iterates through to the second document number, it skips the first row and print the list from second row for that document number and exits the loop without printing the third statement.

Dataset is something like this:

```
Dataset is something like this:
DocumentNo  |SiteID| CltInvNumber | InvDate  | ... | GrossAmount | TotalAmt
BKRA24112015|3060  | BKLF152      |24-11-2015| ... | 128.448     | 128.448
FTRA24112015|3062  | FTCB274      |24-11-2015| ... | 200         |
FTRA24112015|3062  | FTCB275      |24-11-2015| ... | 4           | 
FTRA24112015|3062  | FTCB276      |24-11-2015| ... | 12          |
FTRA24112015|3062  | FTLF163      |24-11-2015| ... | 2372.892    | 2588.89
HYRA24112015|3061  | HYCB66       |24-11-2015| ... | 12          |
HYRA24112015|3061  | HYLF142      |24-11-2015| ... | 0.012       | 12.012
```

I hope someone understand what I'm trying to say.
Here is my code:

```
private void GenerateDirectDebitStatement(string SiteId, string DocumentNo, List<string> ClientInvoiceNumber, string ShortInvoiceDate, string ShortDueDate, List<decimal> GrossAmount, string CustomerNo, string CustVATNo, string SiteName, string ClientName, string Address1, string Email, string AlternetEmail, string PaymentMethod, string SortCode, string Telephone, string AccountNo, string Currency, string TotalAmount)
    {
        //DataSet dt = this.GetSummaryData();
        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.Append("<table width='100%' cellpadding='2'>");
                sb.Append("<tr><td align='center'><h2><u><b>DIRECT DEBIT STATEMENT</b></u></h2></td></tr>");
                sb.Append("<tr><td colspan = '2'></td></tr>");
                sb.Append("</table>");
                sb.Append("<br/>");
                sb.Append("<img src='logo.png' width='50' height='75'/>");
                sb.Append("<br/>");
                sb.Append("<p><b>PARK GARAGE GROUP PLC</b></p>");
                //sb.Append("<br/>");
                sb.Append("<table cellpadding ='0'>");
                //sb.Append("<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>");
                sb.Append("<tr><td><font size ='1'>Registered in England No. 34970229</font></td>");
                sb.Append("<td bgcolor='#C6C3C3' align ='right'><font size ='1'>Document No:</td><td bgcolor='#C6C3C3'> " + DocumentNo + "</font></td></tr>");
                sb.Append("<tr><td><font size ='1'>1-3 Station Approach</font></td>");
                sb.Append("<td align ='right'><font size ='1'></td><td></font></td></tr>");
                sb.Append("<tr><td><font size ='1'>Hayes, Kent</font></td>");
                sb.Append("<td align ='right'><font size ='1'>Customer No:</td><td> " + CustomerNo + "</font></td></tr>");
                sb.Append("<tr><td><font size ='1'>BR2 7EQ</font></td>");
                sb.Append("<td align ='right'><font size ='1'>Document Date:</td><td> " + ShortInvoiceDate + "</font></td></tr>");
                sb.Append("<tr><td><font size ='1'>VAT Registration No. 726 799969</font></td>");
                sb.Append("<td align ='right'><font size ='1'>Payment Amount:</td><td> " + TotalAmount + "</font></td></tr>");
                sb.Append("<tr><td><font size ='1'>Tel: 02083158340</font></td>");
                sb.Append("<td align ='right'><font size ='1'></td><td></font></td></tr>");
                sb.Append("<tr><td><font size ='1'>Fax: 02083158341</font></td>");
                sb.Append("<td align ='right'><font size ='1'></td><td></font></td></tr>");
                //sb.Append("<td align ='right'></td><td></td></tr>");
                sb.Append("</table>");
                sb.Append("<br />");
                sb.Append("<table width='100%'  cellpadding='0'>");
                sb.Append("<tr><td width = '50%'><font size ='1'>To,</font></td>");
                sb.Append("<td align ='right'></td><td></td></tr>");
                sb.Append("<tr><td width='50%'><font size ='1'><b>" + SiteName + " [" + SiteId + "]</b></td>");
                sb.Append("<td bgcolor='#C6C3C3' align ='right' width='20%'>Value Date:</td><td bgcolor='#C6C3C3'> " + ShortDueDate + "</td></tr>");
                sb.Append("<tr><td><b>" + ClientName + "</b></td>");
                sb.Append("<td align ='right'>Payment Method:</td><td> " + PaymentMethod + "</td></tr>");
                sb.Append("<tr><td><b>" + Address1 + "</b></td>");
                sb.Append("<td align ='right'>Sort Code:</td><td> " + SortCode + "</td></tr>");
                sb.Append("<tr><td><b>" + AlternetEmail + "</b></td>");
                sb.Append("<td align ='right'>Account No:</td><td> " + AccountNo + "</td></tr>");
                sb.Append("<tr><td><b>Tel: " + Telephone + "</b></td>");
                sb.Append("<td align ='right'>Currency:</td><td> " + Currency + "</td></tr>");
                sb.Append("<tr><td></td>");
                sb.Append("<td align ='right'>Customer VAT No:</td><td> " + CustVATNo + "</td></tr>");
                sb.Append("</table>");
                sb.Append("<br />");

                sb.Append("<p>Payment for the following item(s) will be credited to your bank account:</p>");
                sb.Append("<table width='100%' cellpadding='0'>");
                sb.Append("<tr><font><b><th>Document No</th><th>Document Date</th><th>Due Date</th><th>Gross Amount</th></b></font></tr>");
                //sb.Append("<tr align='center'><td height='400'>" + Itype + "</td><td> " + DescriptionItem1 + "</td><td> " + UnitPrice + " <td> " + VATPercent + "</td><td>  1 </td><td> " + VATAmount + " </td><td>" + NetAmount + "</td><td>" + GrossAmount + " </td></tr>");
                for(int i=0; i < ClientInvoiceNumber.Count; i++)
                {
                    sb.Append("<tr>");
                    sb.Append("<td>");
                    sb.Append(ClientInvoiceNumber[i]);
                    sb.Append("</td>");
                    sb.Append("<td>");
                    sb.Append(ShortInvoiceDate);
                    sb.Append("</td>");
                    sb.Append("<td>");
                    sb.Append(ShortDueDate);
                    sb.Append("</td>");
                    sb.Append("<td>");
                    sb.Append(GrossAmount[i]);
                    sb.Append("</td>");
                    sb.Append("</tr>");
                }

                sb.Append("</table>");
                sb.Append("</div>");
                sb.Append("<br />");

                sb.Append("<table  width='100%' bgcolor='#C6C3C3' cellpadding='0'>");
                sb.Append("<tr><td  align='right' width='90%'><b>Total Amount: </td><td width='10%' align='right'> " + TotalAmount + " </td></b></font></tr>"); //
                sb.Append("</table>");
                sb.Append("<br />");

                sb.Append("<div>");
                sb.Append("<table>");
                sb.Append("<tr><td><p><font size= '1'><b><u>Terms and Conditions:</u></b> Park Garage Group Plc. If any of your details are <br />incorrect, please inform us at your earliest convenience. If no tax point date <br />exists then use the document date as tax point date. </p></td></tr>");
                sb.Append("</table>");
                sb.Append("</div>");

                StringReader sr = new StringReader(sb.ToString());
                Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 20f, 20f, 20f, 0f);
                HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, memoryStream);
                    pdfDoc.Open();
                    htmlparser.Parse(sr);
                    pdfDoc.Close();
                    byte[] bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                    memoryStream.Close();

                    MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("site@pggplc.com", "naimeshjani@pggplc.com");
                    mm.Subject = "Direct Debit Statement";
                    mm.Body = "Direct Debit Statement Attached";
                    mm.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(new MemoryStream(bytes), "DirectDebitStatement.pdf"));
                    mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("nexgen.simplyms.com");
                    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                    NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new NetworkCredential();
                    NetworkCred.UserName = "site@pggplc.com";
                    NetworkCred.Password = "pggplc";
                    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                    smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
                    smtp.Send(mm);
                }
            }
        }
    }

public void GetSummaryData()
        {
            string conString = "Data Source=PGGPLC;Initial Catalog=Park;Integrated Security=True";

            string query = "Select (a.ShortName+'RA'+REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(10),[InvoiceDate],103),'/','')) AS DocumentNo,a.SiteId, i.ClientInvoiceNumber, i.InvoiceDate, i.taxpointdate," 
                        + " i.DueDate, i.PGGFileNo, "
                        + " a.CustomerNo, a.CustVATNo, a.SiteName, a.ClientName, a.Address1, "
                        + " a.Email, a.AlternetEmail, a.PaymentMethod, a.SortCode, a.AccountNo," 
                        + " a.Currency, a.Telephone, "
                        + " I.SiteId, I.DueDate, I.GrossAmount,"
                        + " CASE WHEN I.ClientInvoiceNumber = (SELECT TOP 1 ClientInvoiceNumber "
                        + " FROM [Park].[dbo].[IMS_ProcessedInvoicesAndSBTIs_test]"
                        + " WHERE SiteId = I.SiteId and GrossAmount > 0"
                        + " ORDER BY ClientInvoiceNumber desc) "
                        + " THEN (SELECT CAST(SUM(GrossAmount) AS CHAR(10))" 
                        + " FROM [Park].[dbo].[IMS_ProcessedInvoicesAndSBTIs_test]"
                        + " WHERE ClientInvoiceNumber <= I.ClientInvoiceNumber "
                        + " AND SiteId = I.SiteId and GrossAmount > 0)"
                        + " ELSE ' ' END AS 'TotalAmount'"
                        + " FROM [Park].[dbo].[IMS_ProcessedInvoicesAndSBTIs_test] I, [Park].[dbo].[IMS_CommSiteMaster] a"
                        + " WHERE I.SiteId = a.SiteId AND InvoiceGenerated = 'N' and GrossAmount > 0"
                        + " ORDER BY ClientInvoiceNumber";

            SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(conString);
            try
            {
                sqlConn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConn);
                SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter();
                sqlDa.SelectCommand = cmd;
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                sqlDa.Fill(ds, "Summary");
                var count = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

                string documentNo= ""; string siteId= ""; string customerNo= ""; string custVATNo= ""; string siteName= ""; string clientName= ""; string address1= ""; string email= ""; string alternameEmail= ""; string paymentMethod= ""; string sortCode= ""; string telephone= ""; string accountNo= ""; string currency= ""; string totalAmount= ""; string ShortInvoiceDate= ""; string ShortDueDate= ""; string ShortTaxPointDate = "";

                DateTime? InvoiceDate;
                DateTime? DueDate;
                DateTime? TaxPointDate;
                List<string> ClientInvoiceNumber = new List<string>();
                List<decimal> GrossAmount = new List<decimal>();                

                foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    var currentDocumentNo = row["DocumentNo"].ToString();

                    if (documentNo == string.Empty)
                        documentNo = currentDocumentNo;

                        if (documentNo == currentDocumentNo)
                        {
                            InvoiceDate = DateTime.Parse(row["InvoiceDate"].ToString());
                            ShortInvoiceDate = InvoiceDate.Value.ToShortDateString();
                            DueDate = DateTime.Parse(row["DueDate"].ToString());
                            ShortDueDate = DueDate.Value.ToShortDateString();
                            TaxPointDate = DateTime.Parse(row["TaxPointDate"].ToString());
                            ShortTaxPointDate = TaxPointDate.Value.ToShortDateString();
                            documentNo = row["DocumentNo"].ToString();
                            siteId = row["SiteId"].ToString();
                            customerNo = row["CustomerNo"].ToString();
                            custVATNo = row["CustVATNo"].ToString();
                            siteName = row["SiteName"].ToString();
                            clientName = row["ClientName"].ToString();
                            address1 = row["Address1"].ToString();
                            email = row["Email"].ToString();
                            alternameEmail = row["alternetEmail"].ToString();
                            paymentMethod = row["PaymentMethod"].ToString();
                            sortCode = row["SortCode"].ToString();
                            telephone = row["Telephone"].ToString();
                            accountNo = row["AccountNo"].ToString();
                            currency = row["Currency"].ToString();
                            totalAmount = row["TotalAmount"].ToString();                        

                            ClientInvoiceNumber.Add(row["ClientInvoiceNumber"].ToString());
                            GrossAmount.Add(decimal.Parse(row["GrossAmount"].ToString())); 
                        }
                    else
                    {
                        if (decimal.Parse(row["GrossAmount"].ToString()) > 0)
                        {                           
                            GenerateDirectDebitStatement(siteId, documentNo, ClientInvoiceNumber, ShortInvoiceDate, ShortDueDate, GrossAmount, customerNo, custVATNo, siteName, clientName, address1, email, alternameEmail, paymentMethod, sortCode, telephone, accountNo, currency, totalAmount);//(DateTime date, string firstRef, string secRef));                                                     
                            documentNo = "";
                            ClientInvoiceNumber.Clear();
                            GrossAmount.Clear();                            
                        }                                              
                    }                   
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lbErrMess.Text = "Error: " + ex.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                sqlConn.Close();
            }
        }
```

My problem is, it skips the row with gross amount 200 and goes to next row and also it exits the loop after DocumentNo: FTRA24112015 and doesn't print next statement with DocumentNo: HYRA24112015.

I don't know where am I going wrong with my logic!

Comment: Have you debugged your `GetSummaryData` method to check that it's returning the data you expect?

Comment: Yes I have, it gives me right document number which is FTRA24112015 but the ClientInvNo it gives me is FTCB275, it skip the row with FTCB274 i'm afraid

Comment: If anybody could pls pls pls help!

Comment: I'd concentrate my efforts on the query. Copy it into SQL Server Management Studio and verify it returns the data you expect in there. Once you've got that working code it into a stored procedure and call *that* from your code.

Comment: Hi ChrisF, thank you so much for your reply, I've ran the query in SQL Server Management Studio, it works fine, but i think the problem here is, in the second iteration cycle when it runs if (documentNo == currenctDocumentNo), it iterates through the next row which is with ClientInvNo: FTCB274 and as the documentNo is not same as previous, it goes to the else statement and goes on with the iteration with the next row with ClientInvNo: FTCB275. I hope you understand what I'm trying to say. Thanks once again Chris

Comment: I've to go back to the same row with ClientInvNo: FTCB274 somehow. The code should be written after: if (decimal.Parse(row["GrossAmount"].ToString()) > 0)
                        {GenerateDirectDebitStatement(siteId,....) method

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is here:

```
                if (documentNo == string.Empty)
                    documentNo = currentDocumentNo;

                    if (documentNo == currentDocumentNo)
                    {
                        ....
```

Because of the lack of brackets after your first `if` test, this will set `documentNo` the first time round the loop and then not set it again until `documentNo` gets reset somehow.

The second `if` test is true the first time round the loop so it will print out the first row of data. The second time it's false so it will go into the `else` where `documentNo` gets reset to an empty string. This means that it will get set again on the next loop.

The way you've got your code means that it prints each row with the same document number but then skips the first row with a new document number.

Comment: I've changed it to: if (documentNo == string.Empty)
                    {
                        documentNo = currentDocumentNo;
                    }

                        if (documentNo == currentDocumentNo)
                        { ...}    but still its the same. Also Chris, it prints all 3 invoices with ClientInvNo: FTCB275, FTCB276, FTLF163 with documentNo: FTRA24112015 and exits!

Comment: @user4921299 All those get printed because they all have the same documentNo.

Comment: ya i know but then why does it print with documentNo:BKRA24112015, skips the 1st row of documentNo:FTRA24112015, prints the rest of the rows with the same documentNo and doesn't print the satement for documentNo: HYRA24112015 at all!

Comment: any idea sir! Sorry but I've no other help if I'm honest!